# PhantomJs crashing when testing Jasmine from the command line

Tags: ruby, jasmine, phantomjs

I'm running Jasmine js tests on a project. I'm using the jasmine ruby gem to run my tests. I had everything working with some sample tests earlier but when I updated the jasmine.yml file with some new tests my tests no longer run.

When I try to run from the command line with `rake jasmine:ci` I get a segmentation fault in PhantomJs.

My jasmine.yml file looks like this:

```
# src_files
#
# Return an array of filepaths relative to src_dir to include before jasmine specs.
# Default: []
#
# EXAMPLE:
#
# src_files:
#   - lib/source1.js
#   - lib/source2.js
#   - dist/**/*.js
#
src_files:
  - app/javascripts/beatView.js

# stylesheets
#
# Return an array of stylesheet filepaths relative to src_dir to include before jasmine specs.
# Default: []
#
# EXAMPLE:
#
# stylesheets:
#   - css/style.css
#   - stylesheets/*.css
#
stylesheets:
  - assets/application.css

# helpers
#
# Return an array of filepaths relative to spec_dir to include before jasmine specs.
# Default: ["helpers/**/*.js"]
#
# EXAMPLE:
#
# helpers:
#   - helpers/**/*.js
#
helpers:
  - 'helpers/**/*.js'

# spec_files
#
# Return an array of filepaths relative to spec_dir to include.
# Default: ["**/*[sS]pec.js"]
#
# EXAMPLE:
#
# spec_files:
#   - **/*[sS]pec.js
#
spec_files:
  - 'spec/javascripts//backbone/views/beat_spec.js'

# src_dir
#
# Source directory path. Your src_files must be returned relative to this path. Will use root if left blank.
# Default: project root
#
# EXAMPLE:
#
# src_dir: public
#
src_dir:

# spec_dir
#
# Spec directory path. Your spec_files must be returned relative to this path.
# Default: spec/javascripts
#
# EXAMPLE:
#
# spec_dir: spec/javascripts
#
spec_dir: spec/javascripts

# spec_helper
#
# Ruby file that Jasmine server will require before starting.
# Returned relative to your root path
# Default spec/javascripts/support/jasmine_helper.rb
#
# EXAMPLE:
#
# spec_helper: spec/javascripts/support/jasmine_helper.rb
#
spec_helper: spec/javascripts/support/jasmine_helper.rb

# boot_dir
#
# Boot directory path. Your boot_files must be returned relative to this path.
# Default: Built in boot file
#
# EXAMPLE:
#
# boot_dir: spec/javascripts/support/boot
#
boot_dir:

# boot_files
#
# Return an array of filepaths relative to boot_dir to include in order to boot Jasmine
# Default: Built in boot file
#
# EXAMPLE
#
# boot_files:
#   - '**/*.js'
#
boot_files:

# rack_options
#
# Extra options to be passed to the rack server
# by default, Port and AccessLog are passed.
#
# This is an advanced options, and left empty by default
#
# EXAMPLE
#
# rack_options:
#   server: 'thin'
```

I don't know if the issue is in the yml file or if there is something else that I may have messed up.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this one out. The issue was in my jasmine.yml file. The path for the specs was `spec/javascripts/` as you can see where it specified `spec_dir` and then I was giving the spec file as `- 'spec/javascripts//backbone/views/beat_spec.js'` which caused phantom to crash because of the repeated directory names.